# Products of Continuous functions: Topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $\mathbb R$ have the Euclidean Topology. Let f and g be continuous maps from $X$ to $\mathbb R$. Show that the product $(f\cdot g)(x) = f(x)g(x)$ is continuous function from $X$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: You need to show that $(f\cdot g)^{-1}(I)$ is open in $X$ for any open interval $I$.  This is easy to do when $I$ does not contain $0$ - the inverse image is clearly the union of open sets. The harder part is when $I$ contains $0$.

Comment: Focus on the properties of multiplication first. You have $|ab-a'b'| \le |a||b-b'|+|b'||a-a'|$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way: Show that $h: X \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $h(x) = (f(x),g(x))$ is
continuous. Then show $m:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $m(x) = x_1 \cdot x_2$ is continuous. Then
since the composition of continuous functions is continuous we have
the desired result since $f \cdot g = m \circ h$.

Comment: Getting use to the site. I apologize for anything not up to the standards of the site. So to show $h: X\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous, I know I have to show for open $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $h^{-1}[(a,b)]$ is open in $X$. However, I am confused about what an open set looks like in a general topological space $X$.

Comment: For this, all you need to know is that the intersection of two open sets is open. In general, all you can know about a general topological space is what is provided by the axioms. To some extent, that is the point. One hopes that intuition from $\mathbb{R}^n$ helps, but that can often lead one astray.

Comment: I believe I have it solved. I appreciate the help.